# Kodi on Android: Edit advancedsettings.xml

Tags: android, kodi

I want to change my buffering settings.

According to http://kodi.wiki/view/Advancedsettings.xml the tags I am looking for is `<advancedsettings><cache><memorysize>` and `<advancedsettings><cache><readfactor>`.

So I am looking for a way to edit the Advancedsettings.xml file. If my installation had been on a normal GNU/Linux box that would have been no problems at all, but my installation is on Android.

I am wondering if there is an addon that will give me a normal editor to edit a file on the KODI system.

I tried the 'Easy Advanced Settings' addon, but it edits the wrong tags (pre-v17?), and a general editor would give more power and be future proof if more tags change.

Comment: can you be more precise.. do you want to change settings from choices or you want to change it manually by yourself?

Comment: I will prever having a general editor, so I can edit the XML myself (I am quite comfortable editing XML by hand), but an acceptable solution will also be an addon like 'Easy Advanced Settings' provided it actually works on my version of Kodi (v17-august IIRC).

Comment: use ES Explorer editor to edit any file on android application

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use a file browser on your device, they usually also have text file editors included. Really depends on which app store you have access to. Or you can ADB it over, but that's usually even more of a hassle.

Answer (score 0):

You may try script.unlock.advancedsettings addon from https://abratchik.github.io/kodi.repository/.

Comment: Alex B, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)